# A set $E$ such that $E$ is dense in $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, and the intersection of $E$ and any line parallel to the axes has at most one point

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

> How can I construct a set $E$ such that $E$ is dense in $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, and the intersection of $E$ and any line parallel to the axes has at most one point?

I am finding this set in order to construct a counterexample to show that the Tonelli's Theorem is not true for Riemann integral because we can define a function
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
1, &(x,y)\in E,\\
0, &(x,y)\notin E,
\end{cases}$$
then $f\notin R([0,1]\times [0,1])$, but we have the following:
$$ \int_0^1dy\int_0^1f(x,y) dx=0=\int_0^1dx\int_0^1f(x,y)dy.$$

Apparently, I also want the measure of $E$ to be $0$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Just make sure they are not on the same vertical or horizontal line. (There is always space for us doing so since each little square is open in $\mathbb R^2$.)

Comment: Here's the comment I deleted again: Try this: Subdivide $I\times I$ into four squares. In the interior of each square, place a point. Now partition each of  the first four squares into four squares. Place appropriate points in these. Continue...

Comment: For fun: find a dense set $E$ such that every vertical or horizontal line that meets $I\times I$ meets $E$ in exactly one point.

Comment: @DavidMitra So basically, find a bijection $[0,1]\to[0,1]$ with dense graph. You can find one by taking the construction of `bof` (see the answer below), and fill in the uncountably many gaps in a bijective manner. Also see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/245409/415941).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $D$ be any countable dense subset of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$. The set of all lines intersecting $D$ in at least two points is countable, i.e., there is one line for each pair of points. Rotate $D$ so that none of those lines is horizontal or vertical.

Comment: +1. This is a very elegant solution!

Comment: I see... Since $[0,\pi/2)$ is uncountable. Thank you!